# how to get text box value in a dynamic table

Tags: c#, asp.net

I got a table that generate dynamically from database with only 1 field then i add check box and text box to it.

```
TableCell tc;
            foreach (TableRow tr in Resource_TBL.Rows)
            {
                tr.Cells.Add(tc = new TableCell());
                ((IParserAccessor)tc).AddParsedSubObject(new CheckBox());
                tr.Cells.Add(tc = new TableCell());
                ((IParserAccessor)tc).AddParsedSubObject(new TextBox());
            }
```

then i want to retrieve the text inside the table and save into database.

```
foreach (TableRow tr in Resource_TBL.Rows)
                    {
                        var cell = tr.Cells[1];
                        foreach (Control control in cell.Controls)
                        {
                            var checkBox = control as CheckBox;
                            if (checkBox != null)
                            {
                                if (checkBox.Checked)
                                {
                                    cmd = new SqlCommand(strSQL, con);
                                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ITUSR_TRNNO", strTRNNO);
                                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", strID);
                                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@REQUEST", tr.Cells[0].Text);
                                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DETAIL", tr.Cells[2].Text);
                                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@REMARK", Remark.Text);
                                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ENTBY", (string)Session["LogID"]);
                                    con.Open();
                                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                                    con.Close();

                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

`tr.cells[0].text` is the text from the table. i'm able to get it.
`tr.cells[2].text` is a cell with a textbox inside. how can i get the text from the textbox?

Comment: TextBox.Text=tr.cells[0].text; use this statement.

Comment: the textbox is inside tr.cells[2]. i wan to retrieve the value of the textbox not the value of the cell

Answer (score 0):

note: off the top of my head

```
   DataTable dt = new DataTable();
       int columnCount = dgv.Columns.Count;
           foreach (DataGridViewRow dr in dgv.Rows)
                {
                    DataRow dataRow = dt.NewRow();
                    for (int i = 0; i < columnCount; i++)
                    {
                        dataRow[i] = dr.Cells[i].Value;
                        //insert statement or save or initialaize or watever u going to do with the text
                       string st=   dataRow.ToString();
                    }
                    dt.Rows.Add(dataRow);
                }
```